# Hardware supporting floats with fraction beyond 64 bit

Tags: floating-point, gpu, precision, acceleration

Is there any computation accelerator (like a GPGPU) available, that natively (this means in hardware, not emulated by a library) supports arithmetics using floating point numbers with a fractional part longer than 64 bit (like e.g. IEEE 754 quadruple-precision)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Hardware_support